# position at start, elements inside a justified div - css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in css that I can't solve. I have a 'container' div, which has several sections as children.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 1000px;
  background-color: wheat;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-self: flex-start;
}

.container .box {
  width: 25%;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
</div>
```

I need the last sections to start showing as the previous sections are shown. I have tried with `justify-self: flex-start` in each section, but nothing, how can the last two sections be displayed in the same way that the previous ones are positioned? . Thank you

Comment: Use `justify-content: flex-start` on the `container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0 15px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25%, 1fr));
  max-height: 1000px;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.container .box {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
    <section class="box"></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `justify-content: flex-start`. If you want to center you `container` div, you'll have to do it differently. You can center it in a parent div for instance, but you can't use `justify-content: center` and exempt the last row.